# Sonarqube coverage with opencover and Nunit

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube-4.5, opencover, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We are currently using Sonarqube 4.5.7 (SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.1) with Nunit and Opencover. Test execution is successful and metrics correctly reported in dashboard. But coverage section in Sonar dashboard is blank and coverage xml shows "Module skippedDueTo="MissingPdb"" for my application module

Below is the configuration I have used in my Jenkins

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" sample\app.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register:user -targetdir:"…\sample\app.Tests\app.Correction\bin\Debug" -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe" -targetargs:" …\sample\app.Tests\app.Correction\bin\Debug \app.dll /nologo /noshadow" -output:coverage.report.xml
```

Comment: What type of project is app.dll?

Comment: Sorry for the late reponse. It is Dotnet application using .NETFramework v4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we found solution for this problem. In this case it was indeed a problem with quotes, wrapping the complete targetargs, as shown below fixed the problem

"-targetargs: …\sample\app.Tests\app.Correction\bin\Debug \app.dll /nologo /noshadow"